# Difference between io.r2dbc.pool.PoolingConnectionFactoryProvider.MAX_SIZE vs ConnectionPoolConfiguration max size in r2dbc

Tags: spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc

I am trying to understand the difference between 2 configurable parameters while creating a connection pool using r2dbc-pool.

I was able to configure the connection pool with the help of the below post:
[Connection pool size with postgres r2dbc-pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57971278/connection-pool-size-with-postgres-r2dbc-pool)

But wanted to understand the difference while configuring max size and initial size while creating

ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = ConnectionFactories.get(ConnectionFactoryOptions.builder()
        .option(DRIVER, "pool")
        .option(PROTOCOL, "postgresql")
        .option(HOST, host)
        .option(USER, user)
        .option(PASSWORD, password)
        ***.option(MAX_SIZE, 30)
        .option(INITIAL_SIZE, 10)***
        .option(DATABASE, database)
        .build());

ConnectionPoolConfiguration configuration = ConnectionPoolConfiguration.builder(connectionFactory)
        .maxIdleTime(Duration.ofMinutes(30))
        .initialSize(initialSize)
        ***.maxSize(maxSize)
        .initialSize(20)***
        .maxCreateConnectionTime(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
        .build();

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a difference really, these are just different ways to create a connection pool.

The initial size is the number of open connections to the database once the application starts.

You can check that with the query:

```
select * from pg_stat_activity;
```

You'll see exactly the number you specified as initial size.

Max size is the maximum nuber of connections that can be open at the same time (you do not control that directly, underlying pool implementation will scale the number of opened connections with higher load)

Comment: Thank you for looking into my post. I am using mysql db and used show full processlist query to check the state. When I set the max value to connection factory object, i getting the desired number of connections populated in the query result. but when i set the pool size using .maxSize(maxSize) of ConnectionPoolConfiguration object, i am seeing only 10 connectoins.